# PCIe x8 card produces boot loop in PCIe x16 slot on Gigabyte GA-B75N board

Tags: pci-express

I have a Gigabyte GA-B75N board (https://www.gigabyte.com/de/Motherboard/GA-B75N-rev-10/support) together with an [i3-3240](https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/products/sku/65690/intel-core-i33240-processor-3m-cache-3-40-ghz/specifications.html) and a LSI SAS9223-8i (a IBM OEM part: https://lenovopress.lenovo.com/tips0856-serveraid-m1115) SATA controller card. The card is currently flashed with an -IT firmware (MPTFW-15.00.00.00-IT), i.e., without an option ROM (if I understood correctly).

The board has a single x16 PCIe 3.0 slot, the card a x8 PCIe 2.0, and the CPU supports PCIe 2.0 as well. I verified that the card works on two other boards - one with a dedicated x8 slot and the other with a x16 slot.

However, in this specific combination, the PC starts but then switches off and reboots before any POST or BIOS screen. If I remove the card, the board works flawlessly.
It seems like it exists quite early in the setup process, as the PWM fan does not even spin up fully (usually it does that).

The board's manual is very unhelpful, as it only says:

> Read the following guidelines before you begin to install an expansion card:
>
> • Make sure the motherboard supports the expansion card. Carefully read the manual that came with your expansion card.

As far as I understand it, the board and card should be compatible as the PCIe version is backwards compatible and a x8 card in a x16 slot should always work. So, what else could be the issue here?

Comment: "So, what else could be the issue here?" - The PCIe slot itself is the problem. The card is compatible

Comment: a long shot, but wondering if this is related to "interrupt 19 capture." I don't see it mentioned in the manual, but it might be the option called "Other PCI Device ROM Priority"

Comment: @Ramhound you mean electrically? that means the chipset should be able to talk to the card but that is somehow hindered by the connectivity?

Comment: @Yorik the card itself seems to have no option rom - at least on the other two PCs, I was not able to boot from devices attached to that card. Afaik, there are several different firmwares for that card, that either enable that feature or not. The previous owner also had no luck booting from the card, neither knew how to update the firmware. Apparently, that is the only issue with these OEM cards - you never know what you get. But I can try to find and set this option.

Comment: @Yorik I tested now various options but the symptom is always the same: if I install the card, I'm not even getting any message on the screen but the PC shutdowns and reboots after some seconds.

Comment: Have you set the "Display Boot Option Control" to "Disabled" in the BIOS? (Page 35 of the [M/B manual](https://download1.gigabyte.com/Files/Manual/mb_manual_ga-b75n_e.pdf))

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes (however the options were renamed in newer BIOS versions). But it does not make a difference

Comment: @reox Have you tried any other cards in that slot? It seems unlikely to me that it would only work with a graphics card in the slot. Oh, and have you made sure there is no detritus in the slot?

Comment: @AndrewMorton unfortunately, I do not have any other PCIe cards here to test. Some years ago, I had a GPU running with that board and CPU but I do not have that card anymore. The slot itself looks clean, but I'll buy a can of air and try that as well.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I finally managed to test another PCIe card, a nvidia GTX 660. The PC boots and works with the GPU just fine. I tried the SATA controller once more but no chance. So it seems the PCIe is working in principle - but not with every card :/